# A plumber left the job in the middle, how do I close out the job?

Tags: contractors

This question is cross posted https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/a-plumber-left-the-job-in-the-middle-how-do-i-close-out-the-job because it was put on hold as off topic for DIY.  (It has gotten more views on DIY than on LAW.  I suggest reopening it here.)

I gave a plumber $2,000.  That is about half of the price on his proposal.

The plumber is no longer on the job. (See [Plumber asking for a lot more money, after starting work](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99203/plumber-asking-for-a-lot-more-money-after-starting-work).)

What steps should I take to do the following:
A. Make sure the plumber does not put a lien on my property for the full price.
B. Get a refund of the money not used.  (The plumber was here for 4 hours w an assistant and bought some 50 feel of 2" black pipe and fittings. That probably does not cost $2,000.)

Would taking him to small claims court be a reasonable way to get the job closed out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: Contact a lawyer, not a bunch of yokels on the internet.

Comment: @Tester101  I was hoping that someone here would have gone thru this before.  Hiring a lawyer is not an option.  It is too expensive, compared to the amounts of money involved.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Exactly.  And anyone who **actually hires** lawyers would *know* that.  Yet another example of how the people saying "hire a <professional>" are yokels who don't know jack-all about the advice they are giving, and on that basis should keep quiet.

Answer (score 3):

> Make sure the plumber does not put a lien on my property for the full price.

Hire a lawyer.

> Get a refund of the money not used

See the answer to the first one.

Honestly, I'd tell the plumber to consider the payment you gave "paid in full for services rendered" and let it go. Life's too short to deal with shoddy contractors...

Comment: Hiring a lawyer is a ridiculous expense for the amount of money involved.

Comment: Not hiring a lawyer can be even more ridiculous of a cost.  The internet people are just providing their recommendations to your question based on their knowledge and experience, what you do is your decision.